# Dynamic databinding in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to bind a property of a polymer component inside a dom-repeat block. In the following (pseudo-code) example, I try to bind a property of elem-a to a property of elem-b:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
      <elem-a></elem-a>
      <elem-b prop-of-b={{prop-of-a}}></elem-b>
 </template>
```

But in this context `{{prop-of-a}}` is considered as the property of the dom-repeats host element.

Is it possible to bind properties like in the example above within a dom-repeat?

Comment: How about you use a wrapper element that will propagate a to b data flow and loop the repeater on that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You would have to bind the `<elem-a>.propOfA` to an intermediate property in the host element, and bind that property to `<elem-b>.propOfB`:

```
<elem-a prop-of-a="{{a}}"></elem-a>
<elem-b prop-of-b="[[a]]"></elem-b>
```

Within a `dom-repeat`, you would have to bind each iteration of `<elem-a>.propOfA` to a unique intermediate property in the host by binding to the iterator instance (which is named `item` by default):

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
  <elem-a prop-of-a="{{item.a}}"></elem-a>
  <elem-b prop-of-b="[[item.a]]"></elem-b>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vpapgE?editors=1010)